# Can Facebook help show (statistics) how people move from place of living to place of work?

Tags: data

Maybe some of you guys know if you or FB can help, or who? Perhaps together with some University?

I got this idea that FB probably holds quite a lot of location information on people (that are using FB with location enabled) during different days of week.

Using this data it should be possible to calculate a (partially representative) statistical view of travel in cities, such as Stockholm, that could help to improve traffic planning, and possibly (which is rarely discussed) how to avoid the need for travel.
The latter however, I guess, would require that people's occupation is identified in some form and mapped to corresponding company locations (incl size?) in various locations.

Regards, Fredde

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ {location} will give you the users location at a given time subject to authentication of course.

Answer (score 2):

The data you are referring at, are sadly, a property of Facebook Inc., so if any transaction might happen will be between them and you (or your organisation, institute, university).

But technologically wise, the software is available and can perform that kind of analysis.

Here's a nice example of what happens when that kind of data is accessible to the public:

http://www.tweetping.net/

To complete my answer, while your idea is a really interesting one, the major problem is the lack of real life data, and the holders of those data are extremely unlikely to release them without any gain for their parts.

Comment: Thank you, Maybe FB would be interest in actually selling this, and thus making some money from this? ;o)

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely FB would disclose this data indeed since it is one source of monetization (remember that for FB, the product *is* the audience, hence the profile data).

Indeed if you have the check-ins (or IP) at various places, it is possible to reconstruct quite a lot if you have a rich database of POIs, businesses, retails, etc.

Fredde, if you're interested about this idea in particular in Stockholm, contact me as this is somehow out-of-topic for this forum :)